# Unable to cover testclass on feedItem

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

Written a testclass on feeditem, but no luck(its 0%) - not sure about the mistake in my code. Please do help me out and de needful.

Trigger  :

```
trigger RestrictFilesOnFeedItems on FeedItem (after insert) {
    Map<Id, FeedItem> contentversionIdToFeedItemMap = new Map<Id, FeedItem>();
    for(FeedItem fi : trigger.new){
        if(fi.type == 'ContentPost')
            contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.put(fi.RelatedRecordId, fi);
    }
    for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT Id, FileExtension,FileType FROM ContentVersion where Id IN :contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.keySet()]){
    if(cv.FileType =='exe' || cv.FileType=='html' || cv.FileType=='edi'|| cv.FileType=='dll'|| cv.FileType=='bin'|| cv.FileType=='cmd'|| cv.FileType=='vbscript'|| cv.FileType=='wsf'|| cv.FileType=='java'|| cv.FileType=='vbs'|| cv.FileType=='vb')
    {
        contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.get(cv.Id).addError('Sorry..!! You cannot attach this file format');
    }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest(seeAlldata = true)
private class RestrictFilesOnFeedItems_Test {
    static testMethod void unitTestInsert() {
        id abc = 'EXE' ;
    Case cse = new case (COMPLAINANT__C = 'Self', STATUS = 'New', ORIGIN = 'Web', TYPE='Claims', SR_SUB_TYPE__C = 'Report Claim', SUBJECT = 'Test', DESCRIPTION= 'Testing');
        Insert cse;
        /*
        Profile p = [select id from profile where Name = :'System Administrator' limit 1];
        User pu = new User(profileId = p.id, username = 'abc@abc.com', email = 'abc@abc.com',
        emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', localesidkey = 'en_US',
        languagelocalekey = 'en_US', timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
        alias='cspu', lastname='lastname');
        insert pu;
        */
        ContentVersion  cv = new ContentVersion ();
        insert cv;
        Test.startTest();
        FeedItem feed = new FeedItem (
            parentid = cse.id,
            type = 'ContentPost',
            RelatedRecordId = cv.id,
            Body = 'Hello'
        );
        try {
            insert feed;
        } catch (exception e) {
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Sorry..!! You cannot attach this file format'));
        }
        Test.stopTest();
        List<FeedItem > lstfeed = [select id from FeedItem where parent.id = :cse.id];
        System.assertEquals(1, lstfeed.size());
        System.assertNotEquals(0, lstfeed.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code, please consider below :

```
private class RestrictFilesOnFeedItems_Test {
static testMethod void unitTestInsert() {
    //id abc = 'EXE' ;
    Case cse = new case (STATUS = 'New', ORIGIN = 'Web', TYPE='Claims',  SUBJECT = 'Test', DESCRIPTION= 'Testing');
    Insert cse;       
    Test.startTest();

    ContentVersion contentVersion_1 = new ContentVersion(
        Title = 'Content',
        PathOnClient = 'Content.html',
        VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
        IsMajorVersion = true
    );
    insert contentVersion_1;//create the the content version record 

    ContentVersion contentVersion_2 = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :contentVersion_1.Id LIMIT 1];//query the contentdocumentID
    List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

    **System.assertEquals(documents.size(), 1);//expected document of size 1
    System.assertEquals(documents[0].Id, contentVersion_2.ContentDocumentId); // matches the id of the document
    System.assertEquals(documents[0].LatestPublishedVersionId, contentVersion_2.Id);  //matches the Latest Published Version Id
    System.assertEquals(documents[0].Title, contentVersion_2.Title);  // matches the title**


    ContentDocumentLink newcontent = new ContentDocumentLink();
    newcontent.ContentDocumentId = contentVersion_2.ContentDocumentId;
    newcontent.LinkedEntityId = cse.Id;
    newcontent.ShareType =  'v';

    insert newcontent;//create ContentDocumentLink record

    FeedItem feed = new FeedItem (
        parentid = cse.id,
        type = 'ContentPost',
        RelatedRecordId = contentVersion_1.id,
        Body = 'Hello'
    );
    //then create feedItem record
    try {
        insert feed;    
    } catch (exception e) {
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Sorry..!! You cannot attach this file format'));
    }
    Test.stopTest();      
}
```

}

It will work properly and it is covering 100% of your trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57738/discussion-between-b1-sfdc-and-avijit-das).

Answer (score 0):

Your test doesn't actually ensure that any validation takes place. If you look at your `ContentVersion` record, you don't even specify a `FileType`. I prefer this style of assertion:

```
// additional setup
FeedItem record = new FeedItem(/*data*/);
DmlException expectedException;

Test.startTest();
    try
    {
        insert record;
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        expectedException = d;
    }
Test.stopTest();

system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException, 'A validation should occur');
// additional assertions
```